# Connection Not Closed in Scanner

Tags: java

I got the command line parameter of the input file name and i have used the Scanner Connection inorder to read input from that text file and after performing operations , i have closed the Scanner Connection.Even then its showing the NZEC(runtime error).

In my machine ,I am working with less inputs, so the error didnot reproduce but in online programing contest websites the error is occuring

Sol:If i use a try-Catch ,the problem is solved.

But please suggest me the reason for this error

```
Whats_next()
 {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    while(s.hasNextLine())
    {
    int x=s.nextInt();
    int y=s.nextInt();
    int z=s.nextInt();
    if(x!=0 || y!=0 || z!=0)
    {
        if((y-x)==(z-y))
            {
                System.out.print("AP");
                System.out.println("\t"+(z+(y-x)));
            }
        else if((y/x)==(z/y))
            {
                System.out.print("GP");
                System.out.println("\t"+z*(y/x));
            }
    }
    }
    s.close();
 }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    try
    {
        if(args.length==1)
            System.setIn(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
        Whats_next w=new Whats_next();
    }
```

Comment: When you close your `Scanner` it also closes `System.in` (and you cannot reopen `System.in` after that).

Comment: Don't set System.in on the contest website and don't close scanner.

Answer (score 0):

You should close a connection in a finally block.

```
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // your logic
}
finally {
    if(scanner!=null)
        scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use a try-Catch-finally block,if we close normally why its not accepting .Can you please answer me

Comment: It is recommended to close the connection in the finally block because if you have multiple catch blocks you will have to rewrite the conn.close()

A finally block will always be executed after a try, no matter what happens. So if you get a exception that  you didn't handle, with the finally block you will be sure that your resources are closed properly.